# compare DateTime of sorted dictionary with DateTime field

Tags: c#, datetime, dictionary, compare, commit

I have an array which needs to be initialized by a Sorted Dictionary. This array will contain integer values, which have been modified inside the dictionary. The purpose of this array is to contain the commits that have been done on a particular day. With the sorted dictionary I will have a DateTime as Key and an integer as the value.

```
    //Array of integers which contains the number of commits that have been done on a particular day
    protected int[] Values;

    //Initializing a new SortedDictionary
    private SortedDictionary<DateTime, int> Sorted = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, int>();
```

Now I fill the sorted  dictionary with days (the period where the assignment needs to be done) and a starting integer value '0' for every day (Inside the class constructor).

```
        //Fill Sorted dictionary with days and starting 0 value (inside class constructor)
        for (DateTime date = assignment.Start; date < assignment.End ; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            Sorted.Add(date, 0);
        }
```

Next I have a couple of commits from my CommitInfo class. These commits contain a field TimeStamp which is a 'DateTime' value. The date of this commit must be compared to the DateTime Keys inside the sorted dictionary. If the dates are equal, the value of the specific key inside the dictionary needs to be incremented by 1.

```
        //Go through all the CommitInfo values
        foreach(CommitInfo dates in commits)
        {
            //For every CommitInfo value go through all of the Keypairs inside the dictionary
            foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> kvp in Sorted)
            {
                //If the dates are the same, increment by 1.
                if (Sorted.ContainsKey(dates.TimeStamp.Date))
                {
                    Sorted[kvp.Key] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now here is where it possibly goes wrong. The dictionary contains the dates as it should, but the integer '0' value of every day doesn't increment when the date of a commit is the same as a date inside the dictionary. I've also tried this if-structure, but it doesn't work either:

```
                if (dates.TimeStamp.Date == kvp.Key)
                {
                    Sorted[kvp.Key] += 1;
                }
```

To give full info, because it could be possible that it goes wrong somewhere else (even with the debugging I did), the next step is to initialize and fill the 'Values' array. Which is done with following code:

```
        Values = new int[Sorted.Count];
        Values = Sorted.Values.ToArray();
```

Could someone help me with how I could get it to work properly? Because I've been trying a lot of things, but none of them worked.

Comment: Are you sure that you will jump into the if-statement? You are checking only the Date-Part of your dates.TimeStamp with the key.
Has your assignment.Start a timepart? If so, your key has as well and the statement will be false.

Comment: Try `Sorted.Add(date.Date, 0);` to ensure you're not comparing the time component.

Comment: @Link I'm 99% sure the problem is in the if-structure. But when I do 'assignment.Start.Date' or Sorted.Add(date.Date, 0) or 'kvp.Key.Date I get a InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @Lor Can you provide a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This would be much easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Link I've fixed the issue. I will post the answer :) Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a do-while loop and used the 'date' as a private filed inside of my class. If I check both datesnow, it will increment.

```
        date = assignment.Start.Date;
        do
        {

            foreach (CommitInfo dates in commits)
            {

                if (dates.TimeStamp.Date == date.Date)
                {
                    Sorted[date.Date] += 1;
                }

            }
            date = date.AddDays(1).Date;
        } while (date.Date < assignment.End.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I saw in your original code was that, while you were looping through the commits, for each one you also looped through the dictionary keys, which is unnecessary. All you need to do is, for each commit, see if `dictionary.ContainsKey(commit.Timestamp)`. If it does, then you can just do `dictionary[commit.Timestamp] += 1;`.

If the code below does not work with your data, then there may be a problem with the data. Let me know if you get any errors and I can try to help.

Here's the way I would do it, which seems to work. First I added the days of January to the dictionary, all with the starting value of `0`:

```
var sorted = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, int>();

// Add the days of January to our sorted dictionary
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 2, 1);

for (var date = startDate; date < endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    sorted.Add(date.Date, 0); // Just add the .Date part to be safe
}
```

Next I created a list of 100 commits, each one on a random day in January (so there should end up being an average of 3.2 commits per day:

```
var commits = new List<CommitInfo>();
var rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    commits.Add(new CommitInfo
    {
        TimeStamp = startDate.AddDays(rnd.Next(0, 31)) 
    });
}
```

Now, to update our dictionary with these commits, we can just loop through each commit, see if the dictionary contains the key, and if it does, update the value of that item:

```
// Update our dictionary with the commits 
foreach (var commit in commits)
{
    if (sorted.ContainsKey(commit.TimeStamp.Date))  // Just compare the date part
    {
        sorted[commit.TimeStamp.Date] += 1;
    }
}
```

And now you can grab the values out of the dictionary as you were already doing:

```
// Populate our values array
int[] values = sorted.Values.ToArray();
```

---

Here is the end result of the dictionary so you can see that the results were updated, along with the sum of the Values so you can see all 100 commits were added:

```
// Display new dictionary results
Console.WriteLine("\nDictionary Contents After Processing Commits");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
foreach (var dictionaryItem in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", dictionaryItem.Key.ToString().PadRight(27), 
        dictionaryItem.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine($"\nSum of all values is: {sorted.Values.Sum()}\n");
```

[image]